# Jquery ui theme overwriting datatables css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I can't figure out why my jquery ui themeroller won't play nice with my datatables I'm trying to include in a dialog. The datatable uses the jquery-ui color and the columns are not readable. Am I missing something?

Here is my HTMl:

```
<div id="dvAdvanced" class="display" style="padding-top:40px;">
    <table id="tblAdvSearch">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Drawing #</th>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Created By</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PartNumber)</td>
                <td>2@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RFQ)</td>
                <td>3@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_id)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedBy)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateCreated)</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnAdvSearch").button();
$("#btnGenPart").button();
dlgAdvSearch = $("#dlgAdvSearch").dialog({
    "jQueryUI": true,
    title: "Advanced Search",
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 900,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Close: function () {
            dlgAdvSearch.dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tblQuickSearch").dataTable();
$("#tblAdvSearch").dataTable();
$("#btnAdvSearch").button().on("click", function () {
    dlgAdvSearch.dialog("open");
});;
```

});

And finally here is my bundleconfig:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery-ui.structure.min.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.min.css",
                  "~/Content//DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
                  "~/Content//DataTables/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"));
```

Comment: You can exclude `"~/Content//DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css` and `"~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"`, these files are not needed when using jQuery UI style, see [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html). Also don't forget to include `dataTables.jqueryui.js`.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thank you for the information, I have removed those two css sheets from the bundle. dataTables.jqueryui.js gives me an error out of the box for some reason saying "classes is undefined" inside that file.

Comment: See [this post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24970/classes-is-undefined-in-jquery-datatables-js) regarding `classes is undefined`.